# Gulp: Why my 'clean' task don't work using the callback function?

Tags: gulp, task, del

My gulp file is above:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var del = require('del');

gulp.task('clean', function(cb) {
    del(['dist/*.js'], cb);
});
```

When I run 'gulp clean', my output is:

```
[12:45:05] Using gulpfile

[12:45:05] Starting 'clean'...
```

The command delete the files of dist folder.

If I remove the callback function, the result is:

```
gulp.task('clean', function() {

    del(['dist/*.js']);

});

[12:54:07] Using gulpfile 

[12:54:07] Starting 'clean'...

[12:54:07] Finished 'clean' after 4.
```

What I'm doing wrong with the callback function?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*del* by itself returns a promise, so if you'd like to use it with a callback you would have to do something like the following:

```
del(['dist/*.js']).then(function(paths) {
    cb(paths);
});
```

Or:

```
del(['dist/*.js']).then(cb);
```

*paths* being an array of deleted folders/files.

There is also del.sync, which doesn't return a promise but an array of deleted folders/files.

Answer (score 1):

*del* node.js module does not accept any callback function as a parameter.

Check the doc on npmjs.com for further details:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/del

Comment: I saw some examples like I have posted, so, what is the correct way to user del in a task series command?